# Table tbody not correctly appending

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

My table tbody doesn't display the correct data after an AJAX GET request. Well actually, after the second iteration of my for loop, it is showing correctly, but after the third iteration and so on, it is appending but it is showing the previous item.

This is what it showing:

[image]

I don't know why it is showing incorrectly in the table in console log, the data is showing correctly.

```js
$.ajax({
  cache: false,
  type: 'GET',
  url: '@Url.Action("DisplayFiles","FileUploader")', //url, // '/Account/Delete/',        
  dataType: "json",
  success: function(response) {
    $("#tblFiles tbody").remove();

    for (var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
      console.log(response[i]['Filename']);
      console.log(response[i]['FileFullPath']);

      $("#tblFiles").append('<tr><td>' + response[i]['Filename'] + '</td><td>' + response[i]['FileFullPath'] + '</td></tr>');

      //var tbodyFiles = "<tr><td> " + response[i]['Filename'] + "</td>" + "<td> " + response[i]['FileFullPath'] + "</td></tr>";
    }

    //$("#tblFiles").append(tbodyFiles);
    console.log(response);
  },
  error: function(resp) {
    console.log('error');
  }
});
```

```html
<table class="table table-striped" id="tblFiles">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Filename</th>
      <th>File Fullpath</th>
      @*
      <th>Date Added</th>*@
      <th></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    @foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
      <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Filename)
      </td>
      <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FileFullPath)
      </td>
      @*
      <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DateAdded)
      </td>
      *@
      <td>
        @Html.ActionLink(" ", "Delete", new { id = item.Id }, new { @class = "btn-xs btn btn-danger glyphicon glyphicon-trash" })
      </td>
    </tr>
    }
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: You're appending to the `#tblFiles` table element directly, not the `tbody` inside the table

Comment: You've scrubbed some data from your screenshot, but the data are still shown in your screenshot of the console...

Comment: I feel like the logic provided in the question, does not match the logic that is generating the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Change this:

`$("#tblFiles tbody").remove();`

to this:

`$("#tblFiles tbody tr").remove();`

and then change this:

`$("#tblFiles").append(...)`

to this:

`$('#tblFiles tbody").append(...)`

**Explanation:**

You were removing the entire `tbody` element, but appending the `tr`s to the `table` not the `tbody`.

The proposed changes will ensure that the `tbody` stays present and that `tr`s are added as children to it instead of outside of it.

Comment: oh i see! btw, it is working now! Thank you Quantastical!